# IF MATCH with multiple lookups

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, match

Looking to create an IF(MATCH) formula on Sheet 2 of my workbook that will look up values from 5 columns on Sheet 1and return the corresponding text. For example if the value from column M on Sheet 2 matches any of the values from column J on Sheet 1 it would return "N", if not it would look in column K and if matched anything there it would return D, and so on. The formula I tried below only seems to work for the first value (N), but none of the others.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)>0,"N", 
IF(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)>0,"D", 
IF(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$L:$L,0)>0,"R", 
IF(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$M:$M,0)>0,"G", 
IF(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$N:$N,0)>0,"F", ""))))), "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether each MATCH is an ERROR:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)),"N", 
         IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$K:$K,0)),"D", 
         IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$L:$L,0)),"R", 
         IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$M:$M,0)),"G", 
         IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$N:$N,0)),"F",""))))), "")
```

---

If the data set is not too large and you can set define the extants the formula can be simplified to:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($J$1:$N$1000)-MIN(COLUMN($J$1:$N$1000)+1)/($J$1:$N$1000=M2),1),"N","D","R","G","F"),"")
```

Comment: Please ask a new question.  When you ask include test data and expected output.  It hard to follow with words alone.